# How to create a shared H2 server in Cloud Foundry?

Tags: java, cloud, h2, cloud-foundry

I am doing some POC for which I have used H2 as DB. Now, in order to scale up I am planning to put this on cloud, but I am not sure how can I make multiple instances listen to one H2 server ? 
One thing that I have in mind is to create a tcp server in one of the instance and then let other instances talk to this one, only problem is how to expose the port in Cloud Foundry ?

```
final String[] args = new String[] {
"-tcpPort", "8092",
"-tcpAllowOthers","true" };

org.h2.tools.Server server = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
```

Can someone please share some examples which I can use to expose this tcp service ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to use a shared persistent database for your application instances. Configuring TCP-based container-to-container routing would be far more complicated, and still leave you with a solution that is not resilient.